# How to sendkeys with selenium in a hidden form

Tags: python, selenium

there have a hidden form ,i want to sendkeys with selenium on python,But failed,How can i send username and password ?Thank You

```
<form action="https://passport.liepin.com/c/login.json" method="post" class="login-box" lt-plugins-valid="0.3955239762649647" style="left: 0px; display: hidden;">
            <input type="hidden" name="layer_from" value="wwwindex_rightbox_new"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="user_pwd" value="">
            <div class="control relative">
                <input type="text" name="user_login" data-nick="login_user" value="" class="text input-xlarge"  data-valid="false">

            </div>
            <div class="control relative">
                <input type="password" data-selector="user_pwd" data-nick="login_pwd" value="" class="text input-xlarge" </div>
            <div class="control relative hide" data-selector="valicode">
```

Comment: What's your error information?

Comment: Your code trials and the error please.

Comment: `driver.execute_script("var us = document.getElementsByName('user_login');us[0].value='wang@1733.com';")
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#home > div.wrap.relative > div.form-box > div.form-content > div > form.login-box > div:nth-child(4) > input').value='upstaris';")
`dianji="document.querySelector('#home > div.wrap.relative > div.form-box > div.form-content > div > form.login-box > input.btn.btn-login').click();"`
driver.execute_script(dianji)`

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **Javascript**. Refer to the snippet :

```
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Firefox()
wd.execute_script("var list = document.getElementsByName('layer_from');
list[1].value='something';
var anotherList = document.getElementsByName('user_pwd'); 
anotherList[1].value='password';")
```